# Bare self type without any class/trait

Tags: scala, self

What is the purpose/meaning of the self type annotation in the following classes?

In the first example, the self annotation is not used at all. Is there something going on in the derived classes?

```
  abstract class StrippingTruncatingWriter(out: JPrintWriter)
          extends JPrintWriter(out)
             with StrippingWriter
             with TruncatingWriter {
    self =>

    def clean(str: String): String = truncate(strip(str))
    override def write(str: String) = super.write(clean(str))
  }
```

Here is another example - in this case there are some usages of self within the class - but why not just use "this" instead?

```
class HiveContext(sc: SparkContext) extends SQLContext(sc) {
  self =>
  // Here is how the self type annotation is used within the class:

  val hivePlanner = new SparkPlanner with HiveStrategies {
    val hiveContext = self

    override val strategies: Seq[Strategy] = Seq(
      CommandStrategy(self),
      HiveCommandStrategy(self),
```

Comment: The first usage was part of a commit with refactorings, so it's most likely an oversight.  The commit also has rare commented-out code, so a lot going on. Probably it was originally a mixin for IMain, where you'd need self.out, before becoming itself the out. https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/7aca20d8d31790569557c87406a74c0c7377de79

Comment: @som-snytt  Interesting - thanks for the investigation i had not actually realized we were looking at the scala source code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems redundant at first, but it can come in handy when inner classes or objects are involved. Compare the following two snippets:

```
class SomeClassWithPossiblyVeryLongName {
  class SomeInnerClass {
    def outerInstance = SomeClassWithPossiblyVeryLongName.this
  }
}

class SomeClassWithPossiblyVeryLongName { self =>
  class SomeInnerClass {
    def outerInstance = self
  }
}
```

So it's an alias that may simply serve as a more convenient way to refer to outer instances of inner classes or objects. It becomes even more useful when you have multiple levels of inner classes.

**EDIT** (to answer further examples from OP)

The `self` identifier in your first example (abstract class) is redundant and doesn't do anything.

However, the second example shows exactly the usage that I originally proposed. This code:

```
new SparkPlanner with HiveStrategies { ... }
```

creates an *anonymous* inner class. So if you replaced `self` with `this` as you suggest, you would get something different, because inside the anonymous inner class, `this` refers to the instance of the anonymous inner class while `self` refers to instance of `HiveContext`.

Comment: Interesting.  I will look more closely at the specific class to see if it has inner classes - and more generally specifically how is the self annotation used. Upvoting in the meantime since in any case this answer is helpful.

Comment: OK I have updated the OP with the  specific usage - and a further question ;)

Comment: I just found another one - and there is NO usage of self whatsoever within the class. It is actually abstract. See the updated OP.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I now understand your answer to #2. Seems like your answer may apply to #1 as well: the "self" is being forced to refer to the abstract class StrippingTruncatingWriter. So then the inheriting classes will see that base class when they reference the "self" .. ?

Comment: In any case i am accepting the answer, pls consider to upvote the question if you think it were a reasonable one.

Comment: The first case #1 in OP is an abstract class and the self => is never referenced within it. So I was presuming the usages must be within subclasses. (But now you say self is not visible in subclasses so that leaves me wondering what were the point of it..)

Comment: @javadba I personally don't see any point in it. Maybe it's just an remnant of some refactor (the `self` may have been used before the refactor and someone forgot to remove it).

Comment: Adding that it doesn't affect the self type. `If no type T is given, S is just C.` http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#templates

Comment: @ghik Yes, I think you're right, I commented on the Q.

Comment: @som-snytt Please elaborate on your "no Type T is given, S is just C". I did not "get" it ;)

Comment: @javadba You didn't get it after reading the link you mean? It means the self-type S is unchanged from the type of the class, C.

Comment: @som-snytt  oh i did not realize there were a  link there until you just pointed it out.